# User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on Starting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I have encountered this issue on on of our SharePoint 2013 farms, I've googled this issue for days on end and still have not found a solution. I have noticed  a lot of people have had this error, but mine seems to be a little different. When running

```
get-spserviceinstance
```

I get almost every service coming up in the list except for the User Profile Synchronization Service. This means I am unable to stop it via Powershell. I have also tried removing the User Profile service and creating a new one, still no luck so far. Anybody managed to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: hi, check forefront identity management service working in application server where you running user profile services, and can you tell which user account  forefront identity management service running?

Comment: Hi, both Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service and Forefront Identity Manager service are both disabled. Are they suppose to be?

Comment: Check User Profile Synchronization Service checklist at [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on 'Starting'](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/14/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/)